# Pandas dataframe reset index count of multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

constructed a dataframe by concatenating several dataframes with the keys [a,b,c] as Index

```
+-------+----------+----------+
| Index | IndexPos | SomeData |
+-------+----------+----------+
| a     |        1 | some1     |
|       |        2 | some2     |
|       |        3 | some3     |
| b     |        1 | some1     |
|       |        2 | some2     |
|       |        3 | some3     |
| c     |        1 | some1     |
|       |        2 | some2     |
|       |        3 | some3     |
+-------+----------+----------+
```

and now want slice it down to the last 2 elements like:

```
df.groupby(df.index.levels[0].name).tail(2)
```

After that I want to recount the remaining elements IndexPos to get this:

```
+-------+----------+----------+
| Index | IndexPos | SomeData |
+-------+----------+----------+
| a     |        1 | some2     |
|       |        2 | some3     |
| b     |        1 | some2     |
|       |        2 | some3     |
| c     |        1 | some2     |
|       |        2 | some3     |
+-------+----------+----------+
```

Is there a way to do this, or do I have to slice it before concatenating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `groupby` on `level=0` and get the last two rows from each group using `tail`, then using `groupby` + `cumcount` on sliced dataframe create a sequential counter for each group and set it as new index at `level=1`:

```
d = df.groupby(level=0).tail(2)
d = d.droplevel(1).set_index(d.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1), append=True)
```

Or using `factorize` in place of `groupby` + `cumcount` inspired by @anky's solution:

```
d = df.groupby(level=0).tail(2)
d = d.droplevel(1).set_index(d.index.get_level_values(1).factorize()[0] + 1, append=True)
```

Result:

```
print(d)

        SomeData
Index           
a     1    some2
      2    some3
b     1    some2
      2    some3
c     1    some2
      2    some3
```

Comment: Wow, very nice. Would've taken me days to come up with

Comment: @LucaR Happy coding :)